# RewriteEngine off; does ErrorDocument still work?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, iis-7, isapi

I'm writing an ISAPI filter for the IIS7 that should map some functionalities of the Apache Mod_Rewrite. The whole rewriting is finished and I now want to implement the **ErrorDocument** directive.

When I do have **RewriteEngine off** the rewriting is disabled as intended. But how about the **ErrorDocument** ?

How is the default Mod_Rewrite behaviour? Does the **ErrorDocument** directive still work if **RewriteEngine off** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will still work.  The ErrorDocument directive is part of Apache's core and does not rely on mod_rewrite to function.

Comment: Thank you. All I wanted to know.